# conditionally rename files based on regex

Tags: fish

I have this function "fileSuffix" which will rename "anything.mp3" to "anything.s.mp3"

https://gist.github.com/chapmanjacobd/4b07d0f64b64ac6fa70056aa44ec02a7

```
function fileSuffix
    set filen (string split -r -m1 . "$argv[1]")[1]
    set filex (string split -r -m1 . "$argv[1]")[2]
    echo $filen.$argv[2].$filex
end
```

I would like to change this functionality to:

1) check if the file has `/\.\d+\./` and if so iterate the filename:

"test.1.mp3" -> "test.2.mp3"

2) if the file doesn't have `/\.\d+\./` then add ".1." between the extension and the filename

"test.mp3" -> "test.1.mp3"

I don't know the best way to do this. I tried `string split -r -m1 /\.\d+\./ "test.test.1.test"` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd write:

```
function incrFileSuffix
    for file in $argv
        set match (string match -e -r '(.+)\.(\d+)\.([^.]+)' $file)
        if test $status -eq 0
            set root $match[-3]
            set n (math $match[-2] + 1)
            set ext $match[-1]
        else
            set match (string match -e -r '(.+)\.([^.]+)' $file)
            if test $status -ne 0
                # file does not have a dot. what to do?
                return
            end
            set root $match[-2]
            set n 1
            set ext $match[-1]
        end
        echo mv $file $root.$n.$ext
    end
end
```

then

```
$ incrFileSuffix foo

$ incrFileSuffix foo.bar
mv foo.bar foo.1.bar

$ incrFileSuffix foo.bar.2.baz
mv foo.bar.2.baz foo.bar.3.baz
```

Ref https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/string-match.html